# Question on Scale-Location Graph

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, variance

[image]

Hi guys, so I am working on an R assignment and I need to find whether or not one variable depends on the other. First, I want to check for assumptions before doing anything so I produced this graph to test for equal variances; however I do not know how to read the graph. I'd appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Please use the self-study tag when asking questions about assignments / homework. Also, I suspect that a bit more detail around "I want to check for assumptions before doing anything so I produced this graph to test for equal variances" as well as your thinking would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This graph shows homoscedasticity (equal variance of your residuals), as the variation of your standardized residuals is approximately the same for small, medium sized and large observations. 
You can also observe that iid residuals, as there is no obvious structure or batch effect visible here. 
So these data fulfill the the assumptions of a regression model well enough to fit it for explaining your y by x.